# How to express references and values in Julia

Tags: memory-management, reference, julia

I have a large array of structs, and I want to create a small array of references to the structs in the bigger array.  How do I express this in Julia?

For example, here is my large array of many Foo structs

```
struct Foo
  bah
end
many_foos = [Foo(i) for i in 1:100000]
```

and here is the small array which I want to have references to the Foos in the big array

```
select_foos = [foo for foo in many_foos if some_condition(foo)]
```

I want to allocate memory once when I create many_foos, and only create an array of pointers for select_foos.

How does Julia express creating a reference to something, verses copying the value?  How do I efficiently create a big array of structs?

Many thanks

Comment: In principle, there's also `Ref`, but that's not intended for this kind of thing. And `view`/`SubArray`, if you want to have a "referenced slice" of an existing array -- but that avoids allocating the new array, not copying the elements (which is done automatically, as Kristoffer describes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code already does what you want. Arrays only store their objects in-line if the element type of the array is of `isbitstype` which `Foo` is not since it has a non-typed field.

There is, in general, no need to think about this in Julia though. You only need to think about memory layouts when passing Julia arrays into e.g. C because there you need to deal with the raw memory of the array.